# Do properties support inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

In my code class `A` has a property, but class `B` doesn't inherit it. Does `@property` support inheritance? Or is it my fault?

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 100

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, v):
        self._x = v


class B(A):

    @x.setter
    def x(self, v):
        self._x = v
```

The error message is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    class B(A):
  File "test.py", line 10, in B
    @x.setter
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: It should be `@A.x.setter`. `x` is under the namespace `A` here.

Comment: You can inherit a property, but you can not modify it independently. If you inherit `x` and add a setter, the original will have it, too. You can of cause define the property as `x` again to get an independent version.

Comment: So `x` is read-only in the parent but read-write in the child?

Comment: @KlausD. that's not what happens when I test the answer below; I get an `AttributeError` when trying e.g. `A().x = 1`, as expected.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  sorry, in orginal code, the class A has `@property` and `@setter` while the B only has `@setter`, and the error occurs. To simplify the problem I just delete the `@setter` of A without thinking too much, it's my fault and the question has been corrected.

Comment: Ah, in that case @KlausD. is correct, and overriding the setter will affect the superclass behaviour; I've added an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

The `NameError` is because `x` isn't in the global scope; it's defined within `A`'s class namespace, so you need to access it there explicitly by using `A.x`. This is a pretty common mistake, see e.g. [python subclass access to class variable of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3648564/3001761).

With properties, though, it can get slightly more complex. If you *add a new setter* in `B`, then there is no problem using `A.x.setter` as shown in [Dean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38301569/3001761). However, if you *override an existing setter*, you will also alter `A`'s behaviour in doing so. I doubt this is the behaviour that you want.

Instead, in this case, you need to create a new property in the subclass with `A`'s getter and a new setter. I think that this is this easiest way to achieve that, with minimal repetition:

```
class B(A):

    x = property(A.x.__get__)  # new property with same getter

    @x.setter  # new setter on new property
    def x(self, v):
        ...
```

Note the use of `property` without the `@` syntactic sugar, as I'm not using it to decorate a new method. If you want to access `A`'s setter from `B`'s setter, you can do so with `super().x.__set__(whatever)`.

Answer (score 3):

It just doesn't know where to get `x` from. You can do this instead:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 100

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

class B(A):
    @A.x.setter
    def x(self, v):
        self._x = v
```

Comment: *"When there is no setter. A().x = 1 will just override the property"* - what? Are you trying this in Python 2.x? Without a setter a property is read-only, so gives `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, You're right. I changed A to a new-style class, so now it's the same for python2 and python3