# Python - Re-assigning parent attribute in derived class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have below code:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self,name):
       self.name = name
    def printing(self):
       print(self.name)

class Child (Parent):
    def __init__(self,name,country):
       Parent.name = 'Roger'
       self.name = name
       self.country = country
    def Output(self):
       print(Parent.name,self.name,self.country)

obj = Child('Rafael','France')
```

Now, `obj.Output()` returns: Roger Rafael France

and `obj.printname()` returns: Rafael

Can anybody please explain why assigning `Parent.name = 'Roger'` didn't change it in the parent class? Want to understand why `Parent.name' is not getting overridden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python subclass access to class variable of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648564/python-subclass-access-to-class-variable-of-parent)

Comment: I think you are mixing class attributes with object attributes

Comment: right and anyway in this case it doesn't make much sense to have `Child` inherit from `Parent` because you are going to be overriding `Parent` attributes and `obj.name` can only refer to a single value

Answer (score 1):

because `obj = Child('Rafael','France')` is an instance of class `Child` and in lines:

```
   Parent.name = 'Roger'
   self.name = name
```

you override Roger's name with a name of an instance `self.name = name` which you are setting in constructor.

To work the way you want, code should look like:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self,name):
       self.name = name

    def printing(self):
       print(self.name)

class Child (Parent):
    def __init__(self,name,country):
       self.name = name
       Parent.name = 'Roger' # but this is awful
       self.country = country

obj = Child('Rafael','France')
obj.printing()
> Roger
```

Comment: `self.name` refers to the same attribute in `Parent` and `Child` classes. I don't think its possible to modify one without the other.

Comment: right but `super().__init__(name='Roger')` will also change `self.name` so that `obj.name` will always be `Roger`!

Comment: @ArthurVigil agreed

Comment: The above code in my Jupyter notebook still results in output 'Rafael'. However, understood your point -  `self.name=name` is overriding the `Parent.name = Roger`. Removing `self.name=name` in the Child `__init__` is resulting in output 'Roger'. I think the order of the statements is not making any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You hid the reference to Parent's self.name when you created your own self.name in Child's init.

What you want to do is call Parent's constructor: [How to invoke the super constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399307/how-to-invoke-the-super-constructor)

And then, access it like this:
[Access parent class instance attribute from child class instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909032/access-parent-class-instance-attribute-from-child-class-instance)